# Text box is not getting cleared

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using Angular.

In my controller I have:

```
mainApp.controller('loginBoxController', ['$scope', '$state', 'mainWebService', function($scope, $state, mainWebService) {

    $scope.usernameText = "";
    $scope.clear_fields = function() {
        $scope.usernameText = "";
    },

    $scope.btnCancel = { 
        width:'45%', 
        height:'30px', 
        roundedCorners: 'all',
        click : function(){
            $scope.clear_fields();
        }
    };
}]);
```

And in my HTML, I have

```
<div >
    <input ng-jqxinput="txtusername" ng-model="usernameText" type="text" id="txtusernameID"/>
</div>
```

So, where have I gone wrong. Please help me.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention - I am using JQ Widgets.

Comment: Where do you call `$scope.clear_fields()`?

Comment: it must work as is. can you setup a plunker...

Comment: Try adding `$scope.$apply()` after the `$scope.clear_fields();` in the `click` handler.

Comment: I cal the clear_fields method on a button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $scope.$apply() after the $scope.clear_fields();
```

solved my issue.

```
 $scope.btnCancel = { 
    width:'45%', 
    height:'30px', 
    roundedCorners: 'all',
    click : function(){
        $scope.clear_fields();
        $scope.$apply();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, create new single page app and run it. It will solve your problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var mainApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

            mainApp.controller('loginBoxController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
                $scope.usernameText = "";
                $scope.clear_fields = function() {
                $scope.usernameText = "";
            },

            $scope.btnCancel = { 
                width:'45%', 
                height:'30px', 
                roundedCorners: 'all',
                click : function(){
                    $scope.clear_fields();
                }
            };
        }]);
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="loginBoxController">
    <div >
      <input ng-jqxinput="txtusername" ng-model="usernameText" type="text" id="txtusernameID"/>
      <input type ="button" value="submit" ng-click="clear_fields()"/>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```